# Finishing a letter

Tags: writing, formal-language, correspondence

I am writing an application letter. The addressee will respond and mention a date for an interview. However, I am and still looking for a good ending.
Would this be correct English / are there other suggestions?

> I look forward to receiving your feedback
>
> Best regards,
>
> xy

Comment: The letters tag is for letters of the alphabet, as the description of the tag indicates. Please do not mistag your question. The correspondence tag has the meaning you're after.

Comment: It's no problem - I didn't realize that the correspondence tag had no description, which would make it difficult to choose if you didn't already know what it was used for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest "I look forward to hearing from you soon."

"Receiving your feedback" implies that you are looking for, well, feedback. This is typically what you receive when you are declined and the interviewer is kind enough to offer you a reason for rejection.